# Why doesn't find and replace in VBA Macro with wildcard setting recognise hyperlinked word as a legitimate part of the text

Tags: vba, ms-word

The below VBA Word macro is run after selecting several paragraphs or for this example all of them.
I attach a sample .rtf file on which to run the macro.
The biblical references at the start of the paragraphs all get a  pair around them, except the one that has a hyperlink. Is my macro at fault or is this an issue with Word 2010.
 As a secondary point it would be helpful to know if this works on Office 365
(I have tried the same, on LibreOffice and it does match even if word is hyperlinked one
(^)([A-Z123I ]{1,3}[^ ]{1,15} )([0-9]{1,3}:[0-9-\–]{1,7})
$1$2$3$2$3
So please don't suggest that I have not made any effort to find if this should work, or that I have not tried different settings. It would have been more helpful for someone to post that it did not work for them to at least show they had taken the time to download the macro test file and actually do a test)

```
    Private Sub RelRefWithBibleName_Click()

     InSelection = False
     If selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Then InSelection = True

     If InSelection = True Then

         MsgBox ("select some text")
         Exit Sub
     End If

     selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
     selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Reset
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With selection

         'Added this to make selection go beyond the start of the selected paragraph
         'so that the detection would work
         selection.MoveStartUntil Cset:=wdCharacter, Count:=wdBackward
         strFindText = "([^13])([A-Z123I ]{1,3}[! ]{1,15} )([0-9]{1,3}:[0-9\-\–]{1,7})"
         strReplaceText = "\1<ref>\2\3</ref>\2\3"

     End With

     With selection.Find
         .MatchWildcards = True
         .ClearFormatting
         .Replacement.ClearFormatting
         .text = strFindText
         .Replacement.text = strReplaceText
         .Format = False
         .MatchWholeWord = True
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindStop
     End With


     selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
     selection.Shrink
     selection.Move
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     selection.Find.ClearFormatting
     selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

     End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping through the hyperlinks collection is no big deal. That said, there is another way:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngFnd As Range, StrTxt As String
With Selection
  Set RngFnd = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "[A-Z1-3 ]{1,3}[! \<\>]{1,15} [0-9]{1,3}:[0-9\-\?]{1,7}"
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      If .InRange(RngFnd) Then
        If .Paragraphs.Count > 1 Then .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
        If .Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Then
          StrTxt = .Text
          .InsertBefore "<ref>" & StrTxt & "</ref>"
          .Font.Bold = False
          .Start = .End - Len(StrTxt)
          .Font.Bold = True
        End If
        If .Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
          If .Hyperlinks(1).Range.Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Start Then
            With .Hyperlinks(1).Range
              StrTxt = .Text
              .InsertBefore "<ref>" & StrTxt & "</ref>"
              .Font.Bold = False
              .Start = .End - Len(StrTxt)
              .Font.Bold = True
            End With
          End If
        End If
      Else
        Exit Do
      End If
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
End With
RngFnd.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I must admit I would not have known how to do that with the hyperlinks. This works great!! Hope I can add this technique to my knowledge.

Comment: With this method is there a way to bold the text that is bounded by the <ref> tags?

Comment: It would have been helpful had you specified that requirement from the outset. See updated code.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. Sorry about not mentioning the bold (option). I added the code for that to which you posted here and it works perfectly. Reason I did not mention is to keep the question simple and address just one point. Me putting in options for bold or whatever would have confused things or so I thought. Your time and code very much appreciated. Take care.

Comment: Why does StrTxt loose hyperlink and become plain text outside the final </ref>.<br>I really need it to retain the hyperlink in that position.

Comment: If did things that way because you never said you wanted it to do otherwise. Code revised.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. I notice that the replacement does not have the first letter bolded but changing the .Start = .End - Len(StrTxt) to .Start = .End - Len(StrTxt) - 1 solves the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Find/Replace expressions, though they could be simplified:

```
strFindText = "([^13])([A-Z1-3 ]{1,3}[! ]{1,15} [0-9]{1,3}:[0-9\-\–]{1,7})"
strReplaceText = "\1<ref>\2</ref>\2"
```

The Word version is of no consequence. For hyperlinks, you could loop through the hyperlinks collection and, if applicable, testing the display text, before inserting the tags either side of them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However my only requirement is to tag everything that matches at the start of a paragraph. It currently misses any text that happens to be hyperlinked. I don't want to loop through all hyperlinks in a separate operation. Interestingly I have noticed that if the ^13 requirement is not there I will get matches on hyperlinked text. So the issue revolves around that for some reason. I did contact Microsoft about the issue. But I chatted with a person that assured me that creating hyperlinks did work....Alternative is use LibreOffice which does not have an issue.